# Restricting access to specific pages

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, session

I am developing a website where user has to login after which they can access their profile. But I don't know how can I restrict users from directly accessing profile page by typing sitename.com/profile.php in address bar. I came across this code while searching on Stack Overflow
It is my login.php script

```
if(!empty($row['username']) AND !empty($row['password']))
{
    $_SESSION['login'] = true;
    $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
    echo '<script>window.location = "profile.php"</script>';
}
```

Now at the top of profile.php I have put this code

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!$_SESSION['login']){ 
echo '<script>window.location = "index.html"</script>';
}
?>
```

The user can still access profile.php by directly typing the URL. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Dont use `echo '<script>window.location = "index.html"</script>';` it causes a round trip to the browser containing the whole web page, just for it all to be ignored because the browser then asks for another page from the server. Use `header('Location: profile.php'); exit;`

Comment: Thanks It worked. What if I don't type exit; in the end

Comment: Add the 'session_start();' command at the top of the `login.php` form as well. Once you start using Sessions, you have to add the `session_start();` at the top of EVERY page in your application, to maintain the session.

Comment: If you dont add the `exit;` PHP continues to run the script. As you already know you want to send a completely different page to the browser there is no point continuing with the rest of that script, and in many cases continuing would do things you dont want done in this situation.

Comment: Thank you for a simple explanation :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a hierarchy and then need to determine what levels of permissions are required to be allowed to view a page. Here is an example list of permissions...

10 - Administrator

9 - Webmaster

8 - Assistant Webmaster

7 - Moderator

6 - Premium Member

5 - Member

4 - Penalized Member

3 - Registered but email not verified member

2 - Human Visitor

1 - Search Engine

0 - Banned Account

So in example when someone registers you set their account to level 3, once they verify their email address you raise the level of their account (database and session) to 5. If you're writing the software you'd be a 10 on this scale for permissions.

You'd want to assign permissions to a session variable such as `$_SESSION['user_permission']` (and use the prefix *user_* for other variables you'll need). When you need to check for permissions you *must* use `isset()`, here is an example...

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['user_permission']) && $_SESSION['user_permission']>=5)
{
 echo '<p>Member-only content visible here.</p>';
}
else if (isset($_SESSION['user_permission']))
{
 echo '<p>Stop causing trouble and you would be able to see this page.</p>';
}
else
{
 echo '<p>Please register a new account.</p>';
}
?>
```

When using `isset()` make sure you have the correct number of parenthesis, common mistake *everyone* makes. If you don't use `isset()` then hackers can gauge the error messages to find weaknesses in your code, so *always* check for things instead of presuming they exist.

Also you don't need to redirect people, just have PHP pull the content for the page where the client is to begin with, it's the *I'm new and I have cool ideas* phase we all go through, you'll grasp the concepts as you realize you're over-complicating things. For example on my **blog/** the edit links only appear if I or another admin/webmaster are signed in, no need to recreate the whole page just for permissions *all* the time, though there are some situations that are very obvious like a control panel in which case you want to check for permissions early on and ensure you serve the correct HTTP error code.

Lastly I've *never* found PHP's `empty()` to be useful, it probably only works with certain types of data, instead I will test if (`$something=='')` for example.

Comment: Very elegant, but **MAJOR OVER KILL** for the question that was actually asked!

Comment: @RiggsFolly If it helps them get better insight to write better code sooner than later it'll mean less hassle trying to figure it all out...and then there are all the other people who ask the same question and end up reading this. It may seem like overkill to some people, it may end up saving hundreds of hours for others.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the Apache config, considering you are using one.  I have used "localhost". replace with your domain.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(php)$ - [F]
```

You can extend the file restrictions by using the following OR conditions in the RewriteRule. For ex. restrict JPG access along with PHP.

```
RewriteRule \.(php|jpg)$ - [F]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Where is this Apache config file

Comment: Really Riggs? Read his question properly. It was "how can I restrict users from directly accessing profile page by typing sitename.com/profile.php in address bar?".

Comment: Really @SeshaKiran that is good advise. He want to be able to stop access to users that are not logged in. Not stop any access to the page completely. Not much point writing a web page and then banning access to it from your Apache config or .htaccess file.

Comment: Agree to disagree. His requirement is that "The user can still access profile.php by directly typing the URL". He did not want that access. So is the answer. You have voted down. Pls. correct it.  Seems you read it wrong.

Comment: @SeshaKiran Afraid not. It would appear that you were in fact mis-interpreting the question and not me!